# Finding intersection of two arrays in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Simplest code for array intersection in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885557/simplest-code-for-array-intersection-in-javascript)

I am writing an app with Mongodb and Nodejs. I have a 'students' collection which contains, among other things, an array with a list of all the courses (course IDs, which refer to documents in the 'courses' collection) a particular student has taken.

I have 2 students, StudentA and StudentB. I want to see if these two students took any common courses.

I have already retrieved the studentA and studentB documents from Mongodb. I want to find the intersection between these 2 arrays in Node.js app.

One approach I thought of was to go through the first array, create a hash map with the objectid as the key. Then go through the 2nd array and try to increment the value by 1. In the end, all the entries with a value of 1 are the intersecting elements.

Is there a better approach?

Comment: I've seen this question twice in the last few days, is there a CS class handing this out as an assignment?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's how

```
a=[1,2,3,4];
b=[3,4,5];
c=[];
j=0;
for (var i=0; i < a.length; ++i)
    if (b.indexOf(a[i]) != -1)
        c[j++] = a[i];
```

`c` will contain the intersection at the end of this.

Comment: For a faster version, make sure you run the `for` loop over the shorter array.

Answer (score 14):

[Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) can calculate [the intersection of *n* arrays](http://underscorejs.org/#intersection). Hence:

```
_(a).intersection(b)
```

or

```
_.intersection(a, b)
```